# SVG not displayed

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm trying to create a SVG shape in my SharePoint List using the below (simplified) code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "svg",
  "style": {
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "viewBox": "0 0 300 300"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "path",
      "style": {
        "fill": "#0000ff",
        "z-index": "2"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "d": "M 50,50 L 200,50 "
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But there's nothing showing up in the column, just a white space.
If I open the browser debug mode the code for the SVG + path is listed.

Also, is SVG only supported in column formatting? Because if I copy working SVG code from column to view formatting it's not displaying either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried reproducing this simple [SVG example](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_path) in JSON formatting & it is working perfectly:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "svg",
      "style": {
        "height": "210",
        "width": "400",
        "fill": "black"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "path",
          "attributes": {
            "d": "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Also, I tried using the `path` in your JSON code in above w3schools example & it was not showing anything. So, I think you are using wrong path which is not generating any shape. Please try again with valid path.

Also check these example using SVG in JSON formatting:

1. [SVG icons](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/master/column-samples/generic-svgicon-format/generic-svgicon-format.json)
2. [Doughnut Chart](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/a51030ba1c8228057d3762e74617da84a55b24bd/column-samples/number-doughnut-chart/number-doughnut-chart-icon-only.json)

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Thx.
The Doughnut Chart was exactly the shapre I wanted to show on a custom card in the list, but it never worked, only in the normal list view as formatted column.